# Trouble with Android Facebook SDK on Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I create app for working with facebook. I download Android Facebook SDK from GitHub, than I create a new Android project for sdk in Eclipse (when I'm creating a new project for sdk, i selected "create from existing source"). Than I added to my project this facebook project ("build path", etc). But when I want to create a new Facebook object, I got unhandled error. It is code:

```
Facebook fb=new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

Where have I do mistake?

Error log:

```
 - 09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.nda.mailinglist.SimpleAndroidMailingListActivity.onContextItemSelected(SimpleAndroidMailingListActivity.java:80)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2174) 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2731)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:129)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:884)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285) 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-29 05:23:21.295:
   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363) 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 09-29 05:23:21.295:
   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
   09-29 05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 09-29
   05:23:21.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at
   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What was error? Please post here.

Comment: So you are making library project from that facebook sdk and adding that sdk project as library project to your code? Try removing and re-adding that libraray project and then cleaning project and see if thats solve the problem.

Comment: I succesfully maked library project, but i can't add this project as library - when I close window for it operation and will returned, therefore I see that project isn't library.

Comment: So you are saying you made Facebook sdk code as library project but when you want to add this as library project you don't see it there in list of library projects?

Comment: I added it and I see a green daw, but than, when I closed the window, I reopen properties and see red cross.

Comment: Also make sure facebook sdk project should be on same drive in which you have your project. For example if you have your project code in C: drive but you have placed facebook sdk in D: drive then it wont work. Both should be in same drive.

Comment: I love you man, thank you very much. I moved android facebook sdk and it works! Thank you

Comment: Great to hear my post helped you. Can you please up my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook sdk project should be on same drive in which you have your project. For example if you have your project code in C: drive but you have placed facebook sdk in D: drive then it wont work. Both should be in same drive.